# An unexpected error has occurred sharepoint 2010 when open aspx page

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I am creating Design SharePoint 2010. I have created aspx page. After completing when I'm trying to open it browser, it's getting error like below one.

> An unexpected error has occurred.
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
>
> Correlation ID: 16117f03-d1b0-4397-b437-5d35ef7c377c
>
> Date and Time: 7/8/2016 1:36:55 PM

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find out the proper **Error message** using you **Correlation ID:** `16117f03-d1b0-4397-b437-5d35ef7c377c`. You can use download below mention tool called **ULSViewer** from Microsoft website. & find the error using this tool.

[ULS Viewer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=44020)

[How to use ULSViewer](https://habaneroconsulting.com/insights/get-the-real-sharepoint-error-using-the-uls-logs#.V39sLaLCfag)

Kindly provide the proper error message here, after getting it using above mentioned tool.

Comment: i installed searching My ID its could not found showing

Comment: First refresh your page. Get the new **Correlation ID** from the page than you need to filter the logs of ULS using your **Correlation ID**. than after check for the unexpected error. You will get the proper error message.

Comment: find id how can view error message @hardik

Comment: check the second link in my updated answer.

Comment: If you get it than kindly provide the error message in new question & mark this answer. so others can get help from it.

Comment: Did you get the proper error information?

Comment: now  i only check

Comment: every re refresh showing different ID

Comment: Obviously, It generated different ID on everytime you refresh the page. But as i already told you that just refresh the page get the ID & use ULSViewer to get the error. till than please do not refresh the page.

Comment: Did you found it working for you?

Comment: getting same error Brother..

Comment: Have you tried steps mentioned in second link that how to use ULSViewer?

Comment: i  have tired brother above u mention 2 link

Comment: You need to find out the exact error using this tool than after you can understand the original error & get it resolved.

Comment: Are you using ULSViewer for the first time?

Comment: yes brother using First ULS  and this first time use sharepoint also brother

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42411/discussion-between-hardik-and-thenna).